# Go cookie authentication system

Tags: http, authentication, go, session

I'm working on a login system in Go (Golang). Previously, I was using [Gorilla Sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) for this, but I wanted to see if I could reinvent the wheel and make it simpler.

Also, I don't need to store many user values—just one: whether a user is logged in or not. For this, I decided to use a map.

```
sessions := make(map[string]bool)
```

When a user tries to login, this function gets called.

```
func tryLogin(username, password string) (http.Cookie, error) {
    if exists := db.UserExists(username, password); !exists {
        return http.Cookie{},
            errors.New("The username or password you entered isn't correct.")
    }

    sid, err := randString(32)
    if err != nil {
         return http.Cookie{}, err
    }

    sessions[sid] = true

    loginCookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "id",
        Value:    sid,
        MaxAge:   int((time.Hour * 12).Seconds()),
        HttpOnly: true,
        Domain:   "mydomain.com",
        Path:     "/admin/",
    }

    return loginCookie, nil
}
```

My `randString` function, which I use to generate a session ID, just reads random bytes and base64 encodes them.

```
func randString(size int) (string, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, size)

    if _, err := rand.Read(buf); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", errors.New("Couldn't generate random string")
    }

    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)[:size], nil
}
```

If a user exists in my database, then they get redirected to an admin area. One of the first things I do on every admin page is call `sessionExists` to make sure they're still logged in.

```
func sessionExists(req *http.Request) bool {
    cookie, err := req.Cookie("id")
    if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
        return false
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return false
    }

    if _, exists := sessions[cookie.Value]; !exists {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

If `sessionExists` returns `false`, then I redirect the user to the login page.

I don't currently have HTTPS working, so I can't turn on the secure flag on my login cookie. But besides that, would this design provide adequate protection against intruders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Concurrent use of map

Quote from [Golang FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps):

> Map access is unsafe only when updates are occurring. As long as all goroutines are only reading—looking up elements in the map, including iterating through it using a for range loop—and not changing the map by assigning to elements or doing deletions, it is safe for them to access the map concurrently without synchronization.

Since your functions modify `sessions` and are running in different routines you need to introduce some locking. Take look at [`sync` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/).

Also see [question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167200/how-safe-are-golang-maps-for-concurrent-read-write-operations).

## `sessionExists` function

```
if _, exists := sessions[cookie.Value]; !exists {
    return false
}

return true
```

`exists` already holds the desired bool.
Let's simply this part and return `exists` directly.

```
_, exists := sessions[cookie.Value]
return exixts
```

Also you may take advantage of named return values and simplify your function:

```
func sessionExists(req *http.Request) (exists bool) {
    cookie, err := req.Cookie("id")
    if err == nil {
        _, exists = sessions[cookie.Value]
    } else if err != http.ErrNoCookie {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    return
}
```

Now let's take a look at [`func (*Request) Cookie`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=12957:13011#L363) source code:

```
func (r *Request) Cookie(name string) (*Cookie, error) {
    for _, c := range readCookies(r.Header, name) {
        return c, nil
    }
    return nil, ErrNoCookie
}
```

The only possible results are `c, nil` and `nil, ErrNoCookie` so there is no point in logging errors:

```
func sessionExists(req *http.Request) (exists bool) {
    cookie, err := req.Cookie("id")
    if err == nil {
        _, exists = sessions[cookie.Value]
    }

    return
}
```